# In an ObservableCollection of TextBlock, can the text in a TexBlock be selected programmatically?

Tags: c#, xaml, observablecollection, textblock

I have an ObservableCollection of "DataItem" which houses a TextBlock. The idea is to bind the ObservableCollection to a ListView by means of ContentControl. I want to be able to manipulate TextBlocks programmatically and those changes to reflect in the presentation and this seems like the most efficient way of doing it.

I populate the ObservableCollection with a few DataItem objects and add text data to each TextBlock. Then I try to select a segment of text in a TextBlock programmatically.

```
public class DataItem: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "") => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    private readonly TextBlock tb;
    public TextBlock TB
    {
        get { return tb; }
    }

    public DataItem()
    {
        tb = new TextBlock
        {
            TextWrapping = Windows.UI.Xaml.TextWrapping.Wrap,
            IsTextSelectionEnabled = true,
            SelectionHighlightColor = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange)
        };
    }
}

private ObservableCollection<DataItem> DataItems { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<DataItem>();
```

// Then in OnNavigatedTo()...

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    DataItem dataItem = new DataItem();
    dataItem.TB.Text = string.Format("This is sentence Number {0}", i);
    DataItems.Add(dataItem);
}

MyListView.ItemsSource = DataItems;
```

// And this is the XAML part...

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <ItemsWrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="7" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:DataItem">
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding TB, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>        
</ListView>
```

// Finally, this is the code that attempts selection:

```
TextPointer pos = DataItems[2].TB.ContentStart;
TextPointer beg = pos.GetPositionAtOffset(4, LogicalDirection.Forward);
TextPointer end = pos.GetPositionAtOffset(8, LogicalDirection.Backward);

try
{
    DataItems[2].TB.Select(beg, end);
}
catch(Exception exc)
{
    string s = exc.Message.ToString();
}
```

The debugger does not even make it to the Catch block. The Operating System shows: System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'

Is selection of a segment of text in a TextBlock by this method not possible? What other strategy would you propose?